# Create a table using another table's row as inputs

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a table using another one and an algorithm. The table simply contains 1 column like this:

```
| user_id |
| 1       |
| 2       |
| etc...  |
```

Then I have a SQL script that counts the number of results given a user_id as its input. I would like to create a table like this:

```
| user_id | f(user_id) |
| 1       | 2          |
| 2       | 4          |
| etc...  | etc...     |
```

How can I achieve that?

**EDIT:** By algorithm, I just mean a SQL script looking like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS actives
FROM (
SELECT user_id
FROM participations
INNER JOIN (SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.referrer=XXXXXX) godsons
ON user_id = godsons.id
WHERE participations.game_id=X
GROUP BY user_id) actives
```

Where users.referrer will be replaced by each user_id from the first table

Comment: "*I'm trying to create a table using another one and **an algorithm***"?

Comment: can you show the "SQL script that counts the number of results..." ?

Comment: I edited the post to try to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the [SELECT INTO statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) to be useful.

Comment: I'm sorry but really can't see how SELECT INTO would work in my case :/ Maybe I'm misunderstanding the behaviour of this statement